# Work with the visible text of a <p> with hidden overflow

Tags: css, text, paragraph

actually I think my question will be unanswered, but I give it a try...
Is there any way, to work with only the visible part of the text inside an overfloating div?

I mean, there is a div with 300px height, and inside of it a dynamic text can be about 500-600px height. I created a toogle to show all. In the 'collapsed' state, I want to put '...' at the end of the last visible line. Does anybody think this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible:

```
p { 
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

more information: http://davidwalsh.name/css-ellipsis

Edit: This appears to work only for single-line elements. Another solution I found for multiple lines: http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/

Comment: As I see this works well only with 1 line. Multiply lines are also reduced to 1 line, and the '...' are appeared at the end of the line, but this is not exactly I am looking for.

Comment: Here is my sample, you can see, only 1 line appeared, but 3 should: http://jsfiddle.net/hFTsT/